# error, Unable to locate package ros-humble-ros-gzgarden

Tags: ros

Running this command on the terminal - "`sudo apt install ros-humble-ros-gzgarden`"
Throws the error - "Unable to locate package ros-humble-ros-gzgarden"
I am running this command on Ubuntu 22.04 running on VM, MacBook M3 processor (arm).
I tried reinstalling the ROS humble and gazebo garden from source but it didn't work.
what shall I do ?

Comment: What's that package supposed to be? I don't think I've ever seen that in any of the ROS repos.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue and solved it with:

1. Run the [commands to prepare Gazebo Garden installation](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu#binary-installation-on-ubuntu) but **without** installing it (we will do it with ROS):

```bash
# First install some necessary tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lsb-release wget gnupg

# Prepare Gazebo Garden installation
sudo wget https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.gpg -O /usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
# Do NOT install it with apt-get
# sudo apt-get install gz-garden
```

2. Install Gazebo Garden with ROS:

```bash
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-ros-gzgarden
```

Sources: https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/ros_installation#-gazebo-garden-with-ros-2-humble-iron-or-rolling-use-with-caution-